# How to host API on windows server 2016?

Tags: python, api, flask, web-hosting, windows-server

We have written a simple API code snippet and hosted it on the localhost. Now we want to host it on the windows server 2016, so that we can get the response from the server instead of the local machine. How can we achieve this? (Tried with **app.run(host='hostname', port=portnumber)** and got this error: "**OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context**")

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import json
import ping

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/access', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "data"
    else:
        return "some more data"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```